# StreamReader fails in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, path, streamreader

This code works in a console application but not MVC:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IDChckRspn)); 
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"d:\temp\response.xml");
object obj = s.Deserialize(r);
IDChckRspn _response = (IDChckRspn)obj;
```

In debug in the console app I can drill down into s, r, obj and _response.  In the MVC app if I attempt to drill into them they will not open.  Sometimes it will work in the MVC but most of the time not.  I suspect it has something to do with loading the file because if I place a breakpoint on object obj I still cannot drill into r in MVC app but can in the console app.  I have similar problems using FileStream in the MVC app.

**Update 1**
After Sleiman's and Daniels suggestion I'm now using this code:

```
IDChckRspn response;
using (var r = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/response.xml")))
{
  response = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IDChckRspn)).Deserialize(r) as IDChckRspn; //'as' rather than a cast won't throw an exception
}
```

but still getting the same result, no exception and cannot drill into the Locals window to look at response.  The breakpoint is on the next line after this code.

**Update 2**
I had declared a variable in the Action that contains this code `var test = "";`.  With that in there I have the problem (break point on return View;).  If I comment out the declaration the problem clears.  If I move the breakpoint to the response= line and step through it works even with the variable declaration in there.

```
public ActionResult VerifyID()
{
  IDChckRspn response;
  using (var r = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/response.xml")))
  {
    response = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IDChckRspn)).Deserialize(r) as IDChckRspn; //'as' rather than a cast won't throw an exception
  }

  var test = "";
  return View();
}
```

Why would declaring a variable in an action cause the .Deserializer to fail?

Comment: Any error messages? Does it throw any exceptions? Being MVC, I'd suspect the that file doesn't have permissions for INETUSR.

Comment: Are you attaching to w3wp process or starting site from debugger?

Comment: You should post more information, like the Exception!

Comment: Running in VS debugger. No exception is thrown and the Locals Window will not allow me to drill into anything.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that it might be to do with the fact that you are not closing the StreamReader with r.Close(), or even better, by putting it in a using clause.

The fact that it works sometimes for you leads me to this conclusion. It could be that your web host process is holding onto an open streamreader and has locked the file. You don't get a new process every time you run your MVC application - only when you recompile.

This won't happen with the console app ass you get a new process each time you run

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IDChckRspn)); 
object obj;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"d:\temp\response.xml"))
{
    obj = s.Deserialize(r);
} //streamreader is closed here and access to the file is released 

IDChckRspn _response = (IDChckRspn)obj;
```

Be careful though. When you are using MVC, it is possible to pass your StreamReader directly to your ResponseStream to stream a file straight into the browser. It doesn't look like this is what you are doing, but just be aware:- in this situation, you would not want to Close the StreamReader and you wouldn't want to use the using clause. When you do, the stream closes before the response is sent, and you get an error. Instead, when the Dispose method on the ResponseStream is called by ASP.NET, the StreamReader is closed automatically for you.

As an aside, the following is a safer version of your code...

```
IDChckRspn response;
using (var r = new StreamReader(@"d:\temp\response.xml"))
{
    response = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IDChckRspn)).Deserialize(r) 
        as IDChckRspn; //'as' rather than a cast won't throw an exception
}
if (response == null)
{   
    //Log or throw new Exception("Couldn't convert'd:\temp\response.xml' to IDChckRspn");
}
//else... success...use response
```

Comment: It sounds like good practice but unfortunately did not clear the problem.  I copied and pasted your code verbatim and got the same result.  Restarted VS for good measure and it still failed :(.

Comment: Did you see the comments asking for what Exception is thrown? Are there any?

Comment: Again great suggestions but still the same result.  No exception and cannot drill into the Locals Window.  I also added in Sleiman's HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/response.xml")) and again got the same failure.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that you shouldn't access local files in web applications, instead you can put your files in `App_Data` folder

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/response.xml")))
{
// make sure you use using statement, it closes the file for you
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion but doesn't clear the error.  Even when I incorporated yours into Daniel's second version of the code.